# Android dialog dismiss delay

Tags: android, dialog, dismiss

Have anyone noticed that after

```
mDialog.dismiss();
```

the OnDismissListener is triggered approximately 0.1s later?
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Give it a sec, that's why you have this delay, i don't think it's intentional anyway.

Comment: I do not see any delay in mine anyway...

Comment: @g00dy, I still don't like that delay, because if I want to do something after dismiss I get 0.1s lag.

Comment: Well, if you share with us why this delay is so bothering for you, then we could help with a workaround, but there isn't any guarantee that the delay next will be even 0.1, it could be 0.2 ..

Comment: After I dismiss dialog, I start animation. And that 0.1s lag is **VERY** noticeable

Comment: overWrite the onDismiss() method and start the animation in that.